# How long does the JVM wait for a thread

Tags: java, jvm

Hi Every JAVA Developper,
I have juste a simple Question about JVM, i want to know how long the JVM will wait for a thread ?
For Example, take a look at this code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("myShellCommand -p1 v1 -p2 v2");
 p.waitFor();
 System.out.println("End ....:)");
}
```

Suppose that "myShellCommand" running for ever, whats happen then ? the JVM still also waiting for ever ?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. It should run forever.

Answer (score 1):

the waitFor method causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process represented by this Process object has terminated. This method returns immediately if the subprocess has already terminated. If the subprocess has not yet terminated, the calling thread **will be blocked until the subprocess exits**.(From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29)).

Based on the documentation, I think that it will run forever.

Answer (score 1):

@Kaoutar

If your requirement is to launch the process and then exit the JVM after a reasonable time period, e.g. 10 minutes, then you could do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Thread subProcessThread = new Thread(new Runnable()
                          {
                                @Override
                                public void run()
                                {
                                  Process p;
                                  try
                                  {
                                    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("myShellCommand -p1 v1 -p2 v2");
                                    p.waitFor();
                                    System.out.println("End ....:)");
                                  }
                                  catch (IOException e)
                                  {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                  }
                                  catch (InterruptedException e)
                                  {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                  }
                                }
                          });
subProcessThread.start();
long waitTimeInMillis = 10 * 60 * 1000;
subProcessThread.join(waitTimeInMillis);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the JVM would continue to wait for the launched process to terminate.

However, you could launch another "process monitor" thread and that could wait/sleep for a reasonable time and then **interrupt the main thread**.

1. As per the javadoc of the waitFor method
   if the current thread is interrupted by another thread while it is 
    waiting, then the wait is ended and an **InterruptedException** is thrown.